# import PhysicsConstraint not working

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine

The code below is not working.
**In the system console it says no module named PhysicsConstraints**

```
import PhysicsConstraints
from bge import logic

cont = logic.getCurrentController()
c  = cont.owner

if (c["init"] == 0):
    c["init"] = 1
    physicsid = c.getPhysicsId()
    vehicle = PhysicsConstraints.createConstraint(physicsid,0,11)
    c["cid"] = vehicle.getConstraintId()
    vehicle = PhysicsConstraints.getVehicleConstraint(c["cid"])

# Wheels

    act1 = cont.actuators["wheel1"]
    wheel1 = act1.owner

    act2 = cont.actuators["wheel2"]
    wheel2 = act2.owner

    act3 = cont.actuators["wheel3"]
    wheel3 = act3.owner

    act4 = cont.actuators["wheel4"]
    wheel4 = act4.owner


    wheelAttachDirLocal = [0,0,-1]
    wheelAxleLocal = [-1,0,0]

    wheelRadius = 0.8
    suspensionRestLength = 0.28


    hasSteering = 1
# wheel1
    wheelAttachPosLocal = [1.0 ,1.5, 0]
    vehicle.addWheel(wheel1,wheelAttachPosLocal,wheelAttachDirLocal,wheelAxleLocal,suspensionRestLength,wheelRadius,hasSteering)
# wheel 2
    wheelAttachPosLocal = [-1.0 ,1.5, 0]
    vehicle.addWheel(wheel2,wheelAttachPosLocal,wheelAttachDirLocal,wheelAxleLocal,suspensionRestLength,wheelRadius,hasSteering)


    hasSteering = 0
# wheel 3
    wheelAttachPosLocal = [1.0 ,-1.4, 0]
    vehicle.addWheel(wheel3,wheelAttachPosLocal,wheelAttachDirLocal,wheelAxleLocal,suspensionRestLength,wheelRadius,hasSteering)
# wheel 4
    wheelAttachPosLocal = [-1.0 ,-1.4, 0]
    vehicle.addWheel(wheel4,wheelAttachPosLocal,wheelAttachDirLocal,wheelAxleLocal,suspensionRestLength,wheelRadius,hasSteering)

else:

    vehicle = PhysicsConstraints.getVehicleConstraint(c["cid"])

    #vehicle.setSteeringValue(steer,0)  
    #vehicle.setSteeringValue(steer,1)

# Acceleration

    vehicle.applyEngineForce(c["force"],0)
    vehicle.applyEngineForce(c["force"],1)

# Brakes

    vehicle.applyBraking(c["brake"],0)
    vehicle.applyBraking(c["brake"],1)
    vehicle.applyBraking(c["brake"],2)
    vehicle.applyBraking(c["brake"],3)

# Suspension

    influence = 0.1
    vehicle.setRollInfluence(influence,0)
    vehicle.setRollInfluence(influence,1)
    vehicle.setRollInfluence(influence,2)
    vehicle.setRollInfluence(influence,3)

    stiffness = 10
    vehicle.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness,0)
    vehicle.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness,1)
    vehicle.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness,2)
    vehicle.setSuspensionStiffness(stiffness,3)

    damping = 0.5
    vehicle.setSuspensionDamping(damping,0)
    vehicle.setSuspensionDamping(damping,1)
    vehicle.setSuspensionDamping(damping,2)
    vehicle.setSuspensionDamping(damping,3)

    compression = 0.5
    vehicle.setSuspensionCompression(compression,0)
    vehicle.setSuspensionCompression(compression,1)
    vehicle.setSuspensionCompression(compression,2)
    vehicle.setSuspensionCompression(compression,3)

    friction = 1.0
    vehicle.setTyreFriction(friction,0)
    vehicle.setTyreFriction(friction,1)
    vehicle.setTyreFriction(friction,2)
    vehicle.setTyreFriction(friction,3)
```

The logic editor window looks like this:
[image]
What should I do to run this code?

Comment: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bge.constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
import PhysicsConstraints
...
vehicle = PhysicsConstraints.createConstraint(physicsid,0,11)
...
```

with

```
import bge.constraints
...
vehicle = bge.constraints.createConstraint(physicsid,0,11)
...
```

and so on.